# Instance Initialization Block not called with ObjectInputStream, how to recreate an object?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```java
import java.io.*;

public class StackOverflow implements Serializable
{
    private transient Object stackOverflow; 

    {
        stackOverflow = new Object();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        File object = new File("/Users/user/Desktop/stackoverflow.txt");

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(object);
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
            oos.writeObject(new StackOverflow());
        }

        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(object);
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
            StackOverflow stackOverflow = (StackOverflow) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(stackOverflow.stackOverflow); //output: null
        }
    }
}
```

Since object is not serializable I made it transient:

```java
private transient Object stackOverflow;
```

The problem is, the IIB (Instance Initialization Block) is not executed on the `readObject`-method. So the question is how to I recreate the object.stackoverflow variable? And since it is private, I cannot set it from the outside.

Comment: Override `readObject`?

Comment: readObject is final and since the variable is private I cannot access it from the outside. I thought maybe there is a simple way of doing this.

Comment: Is `readObject` final? The documentation for [`ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) says "Serializable classes that require special handling during the serialization and deserialization process should implement the following methods: ... `private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)`".

Comment: I thought you meant override the ObjectInputStream method readObject, but I had to declare the following method (in the Stackoverflow class) to make it work:

```@Serial private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream) { this.stackOverflow = new Object(); }```

If you create an answer for this I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIB is copied into all constructors of a class by the compiler and it is executed as the last statement of each constructor. `FileInputStream#readObject` however, does not call any constructors of serialized classes that implement `Serializable`. Only the default constructor of parent classes that do not implement `Serializable` are called.

Since your property `stackOverflow` is `transient` it is not serialized, and since the constructor of `StackOverflow` is not called during deserialization, the property is not reinitialized.

If you need to do some initialization while deserialization you can do this by implementing `Serializable#readObject)

```
public class StackOverflow implements Serializable {
   private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
      ...
   }
}
```

@see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html

If you don't mind, I'd like to recommend to be very careful with IIBs. They are rarely used and  therefore hard to understand. It is better to simply initialize a property directly like

```
private Cat animal = new Cat();
```

More elaborate initialization can be done in constructors, this is what they are used for in the first place.
If you have more then one constructor and you don't want to repeat the same initialization in every constructor, you can delegate to another constructor by calling `this(...)`, or simply by using a method.